# How to randomize order of pictures appearing on a page with labels?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, controls

I've got a method in my control page that displays 4 images with their 4 labels. What I am trying to achieve is to have these 4 images with their corresponding labels displayed randomly each time the page is loaded.

The control page has a panel with set locations for each label and each image. How do I randomize it? 
This is what I have:

```
        Label1.Text = DBTable.WText1;
        Label2.Text = DBTable.WText2;
        Label3.Text = DBTable.WText3;


        Image1.ImageUrl = DBTable.WImage1;
        Image2.ImageUrl = DBTable.WImage2;
        Image3.ImageUrl = DBTable.WImage3;

        Label4.Text = DBTable.CorrectText;
        Image4.ImageUrl = DBTable.CorrectImage;
```

Any advice or help is appreciated

Comment: Throw the images into a List, pick from list with random index? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried using a random method to randomize the numbers at the end of the label and image tags, such as 
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int rand = rnd.Next(1, 5);

but I don't know how to implement this and I realized that if I do so the markup of the image button tags will be affected since I've set the images to move.

How do put the images in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class RandomImageTest : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a list to hold final image information
            List<ImageData> images = new List<ImageData>();

            // Create a temporary list for initial image data
            List<ImageData> imagesTemp = new List<ImageData>();
            Random rnd = new Random();

            // Add image data to temporary list
            imagesTemp.Add(new ImageData() { Label = "Label 1", Path = "//image1.gif" });
            imagesTemp.Add(new ImageData() { Label = "Label 2", Path = "//image2.gif" });
            imagesTemp.Add(new ImageData() { Label = "Label 3", Path = "//image3.gif" });
            imagesTemp.Add(new ImageData() { Label = "Label 4", Path = "//image4.gif" });

            // Use a for loop to retrieve a random item from the temporary list
            // Copy that item to the final list for later use
            // Remove the used item from the temporary list so that it is not retrieved more than once
            for (int i = imagesTemp.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                int rand = rnd.Next(0, i);
                images.Add(imagesTemp[rand]);
                imagesTemp.RemoveAt(rand);
            }

            // Use the final (randomised) list to set the properties of the four images and labels
            Label1.Text = images[0].Label;
            Label2.Text = images[1].Label;
            Label3.Text = images[2].Label;
            Label4.Text = images[3].Label;


            Image1.ImageUrl = images[0].Path;
            Image2.ImageUrl = images[1].Path;
            Image3.ImageUrl = images[2].Path;
            Image4.ImageUrl = images[3].Path;
        }

        // A class to store any information regarding an image
        // Can add 'alt' text etc. if required
        private class ImageData
        {
            public string Label { get; set; }
            public string Path { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! what you gave me worked. I've got a further question now: How do I repeat this random method for the next row of my database to display four more pictures with labels and to get a different randomization order?

Comment: You can move the code used above into a method that accepts a list of ImageData to randomise, then returns a list of ImageData (that has been randomised). Regarding the database, depending on how you retrieve the data, just swap out the hard coded label texts and paths with the appropriate data - this could also be carried out in another method. This way you can loop as many times as you wish just calling the methods as required.